# Draw table count with special values (Numbers software)

Tags: excel, numbers

I use the Numbers software to make the table
I need three formulas for the bottom table. (for draw table count with special values)

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: (Maybe help you too)

for COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(Table 1::B,"<10")
=COUNTIF(Table 1::B, ">10")
=COUNTIF(Table 1::B, 20) or =COUNTIF(Table 1::B,"=20")
```

If you want "greater than or equal to 10" it would be

```
=COUNTIF(Table 1::B, ">=10")
```

for AVERAGEIF:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Table 1::B,">10",Table 1::B)
=AVERAGEIFS(Table 1::B,Table 1::B,">=15",Table 1::B,"<=20")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `countifs` and `countif`, eg:

```
=COUNTIF("B:B", "<"&10) 'counts everything lower than 10 in column B

=COUNTIFS("B:B", ">=10", "B:B", "<20") '10 or higher, lower than 20

=COUNTIF("B:B", "20") 'you get the idea
```